# Google Bar Chart data preparation -- Group by Column

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create a google chart from the below data.

```
        Year        Product Value
        2015            A     10
        2015            B     20
        2016            C     30
        2016            D     40
```

Is this the right data for my google chart, using arrayToDataTable function, but not getting the desired output.
I want Product as the legends, Year as the xAxis value and the value should define the bars.
Thanks

Comment: The above table I fetched from sql server 2008 r2 query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each chart type has a specific [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#data-format) you can check

typically, for most chart types, all columns after the first should be a number

unless you're using annotations, tooltips, or some other role

as such, the data would need to look similar to...

```
      ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      ['2015', 10, 20, null, null],
      ['2016', null, null, 30, 40],
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      ['2015', 10, 20, null, null],
      ['2016', null, null, 30, 40],
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to transpose the data from sql server into the format preferred by the chart,
first create a data view, with calculated columns for each unique product

then aggregate the view, grouping on year, using the `group()` method

use the aggregated data table to draw the chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // raw table data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Product', 'Value'],
      [2015, 'A', 10],
      [2015, 'B', 20],
      [2016, 'C', 30],
      [2016, 'D', 40]
    ]);

    // format year as string
    var formatYear = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '0000'
    });
    formatYear.format(data, 0);

    // create data view
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    // init column arrays
    var aggColumns = [];

    // use formatted year as first column
    var viewColumns = [{
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      type: 'string'
    }];

    // build view & agg column for each product
    data.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (product, index) {
      // add view column
      viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === product) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 2);
          }
          return null;
        },
        label: product,
        type: 'number'
      });

      // add agg column
      aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index + 1,
        label: product,
        type: 'number'
      });
    });

    // set view columns
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    // agg view by year
    var group = google.visualization.data.group(
      view,
      [0],
      aggColumns
    );

    // draw chart
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(group);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Just to conclude the discussion, any idea how to transpose the table which I am dynamically getting from sql server to the above you suggested.

Comment: Yap, great, its very helpful. Its just worked for me.

Comment: Yes I do accept as answered, and wanna thank you for this help

Comment: How to add annotation column while grouping like this?

Comment: @Artur -- you would need to add the annotation column to the data table created by the group operation, afterwards. if you have a question somewhere, please send the link and I will try to answer...