# How to "group by" columns in Google charts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, group-by, google-visualization

I'm pretty new to development and I am currently working on a JEE website displaying Google Charts.
I have no problem with the majority of charts, but one looks "impossible" to me... This chart must display the number of uncategorized tickets by quarter, and by department.

My Java class generates an array which has this format, according to what I’m getting from DB. :

> [ "Q2", "Applications", 115 ],[ "Q2", "Datacenter & Site ops", 343], 
>   [ "Q1", "Applications", 215 ],[ "Q1", "Datacenter & Site ops", 300 ]

Here is my function to get these arrays code (I’m using struts2 framework) :

```
private void generateUncategorizedTicketsDept()
{
    /*
     * Generating data for UncategorizedTicketsDept
     */
    ArrayList<QuartUncategorizedTicketsDept> qutdList = new ArrayList<>();

    qutdList = QuartUncategorizedTicketsDeptDAO.getQuarterUncategorizedTicketsDept(year, quarter);

    if (qutdList == null || qutdList.size() == 0)
    {
        addActionError(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else
    {
        for (QuartUncategorizedTicketsDept qutd : qutdList)
        {           
            //Creating an array to provide to chart
            uncategorizedTicketsDeptData += "[ \"Q" + qutd.getQuarter() + "\", \"" + qutd.getDepartmentName() 
            + "\", " + qutd.getUncategorizedTicketsNb()
            + " ],";
        }
    }
    //Delete last comma in the arrays list
    uncategorizedTicketsDeptData = Utils.deleteLastComma(uncategorizedTicketsDeptData);
}
```

And here is my JS code (you can see that the chart works fine when quarter is commented) :

```
    /*
//Uncategorized tickets by department chart
 */
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages : [ 'corechart', 'bar' ]
});
$(document).ready(google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisUncategorizedTickColors));

function drawAxisUncategorizedTickColors() {

    // Get chart data from HTML page and put it into an array
    var uncategorizedTicketsDeptData = $("span#uncategorizedTicketsDeptData").text();
    var arrayUncategorizedTicketsDeptData = JSON.parse("[" + uncategorizedTicketsDeptData.trim() + "]");

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
//  data.addColumn('string', 'Quarter');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Uncategorized tickets ');

    //Create chart row
//  data.addRows([
//      [ "Q2", "Applications", 115 ],[ "Q2", "Datacenter & Site ops", 343 ],
//      [ "Q1", "Applications", 215 ],[ "Q1", "Datacenter & Site ops", 300 ]
//      ]);
    data.addRows([
        [ "Applications", 115 ],[ "Datacenter & Site ops", 343 ],
        [ "Applications", 215 ],[ "Datacenter & Site ops", 300 ]
        ]);
//  data.addRows(arrayUncategorizedTicketsDeptData);

    //Sort by quarter, then by top uncategorized department
    data.sort({column: 0, desc: true}, {column: 2, desc: true});

    //Create a view for bars annotations
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
    }]);


    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Uncategorized tickets by Department',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('uncategorizedTicketsByDeptChart_div'));

    chart.draw(view, options);

};
```

My problem is that I can display the uncategorized tickets by quarter, or the uncategorized tickets by department, but I am unable to get the departments “grouped by” quarter.
I have found this topic that looks like my problem, but I couldn’t get a chart by quarter, with one bar by department…

Do you have any idea how I could do?
Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT**
Added a snippet of my chart and an image of expected chart.

```js
/*
//Uncategorized tickets by department chart
 */
google.charts.load('current', {
 packages : [ 'corechart', 'bar' ]
});
$(document).ready(google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisUncategorizedTickColors));

function drawAxisUncategorizedTickColors() {

 // Get chart data from HTML page and put it into an array
 var uncategorizedTicketsDeptData = $("span#uncategorizedTicketsDeptData").text();
 var arrayUncategorizedTicketsDeptData = JSON.parse("[" + uncategorizedTicketsDeptData.trim() + "]");

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
// data.addColumn('string', 'Quarter');
 data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Uncategorized tickets ');

 //Create chart row
// data.addRows([
//  [ "Q2", "Applications", 115 ],[ "Q2", "Datacenter & Site ops", 343 ],
//  [ "Q1", "Applications", 215 ],[ "Q1", "Datacenter & Site ops", 300 ]
//  ]);
 data.addRows([
  [ "Applications", 115 ],[ "Datacenter & Site ops", 343 ],
  [ "Applications", 215 ],[ "Datacenter & Site ops", 300 ]
  ]);
// data.addRows(arrayUncategorizedTicketsDeptData);
 
 //Sort by quarter, then by top uncategorized department
 data.sort({column: 0, desc: true}, {column: 2, desc: true});

 //Create a view for bars annotations
 var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
 view.setColumns([0, 1, {
     calc: 'stringify',
     sourceColumn: 1,
     type: 'string',
     role: 'annotation'
 }]);
 

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Uncategorized tickets by Department',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('uncategorizedTicketsByDeptChart_div'));

    chart.draw(view, options);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<hr>
<div id="uncategorizedTicketsByDeptChart_div" style="width: 90%; height: 500px; padding: 10px;"></div>
<hr>
```

Here is an example of what I would like to do (done with Excel in 2 minutes) :
[Excel chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQpkA.png)

Comment: use a data view to move the departments into their own column, see the last __EDIT__ in --> [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367600/5090771)

Comment: Thank you very much WhiteHat!

Comment: My chart is now working.
I have create a jsfiddle to share it, if someone needs :https://jsfiddle.net/Gachdel/3nzfvtrh/#&togetherjs=npdquziqKw

Thanks again!