# Google chart to visualize multidimensional data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have multidimensional data that I need to visualize in Google charts. What I mean with multidimensional is that it might contain multiple dimensional normal columns (String, date... ) and multiple numerical columns.

For example, consider the following simple data; composed of three String dimensions and a numerical value:

```
Profession (String) |  Country (String) | Gender (String) |  income (Numerical)
Doctor                    Germany             male              30000
Engineer                  Austria             female            20000
```

Normal google charts (e.g. Bar or Line) has typically two dimensions; i.e., it can visualize data of the form (for example):

```
Profession |  income
Doctor        30000
Engineer      20000
```

Which has only one dimension and a numerical value.

Currently, my trick is to use the additional dimensions as annotations, which is not the best way around to do it. Any suggestions about possible other charts/settings to visualize such multidimensional data?

Comment: check the last __EDIT__ in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367600/5090771)...

Answer (score 0):

If you use ScatterChart, or LineChart, you can specify the point shape for a more discrete dimension, the number of sides of polygons, the indentation, and rotation for more dimensions. The point size and fill color, the stroke size and stroke color are a few more dimensions.  See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points